# Editing multiple destination files with ansible?

Tags: yaml, ansible

I am currently trying to update all the wp-config.php files on multiple servers. 
This below should work but it wont allow me to use regexp for the destination.

Does anyone know an alternate way to do this?

```
---
- hosts: blah.blah.net
  user: blah
  sudo: true
  tasks:
  - name: add a new string before the match
    lineinfile: dest='\/home\/.*\/public_html\/wp-config.php'
                regexp='^\/\*\* MySQL database password \*\/'
                insertbefore='^\/\*\* MySQL database password \*\/'
                line='define("DISALLOW_FILE_MODS", true);'
```

Comment: `with_items` with a list of your users. If your list of users is fairly limited and static, you could maintain it in a var file. Otherwise, perhaps some kind of task that scanned the home directory into a var that you could use with `with_items`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've already experienced, a regular expression won't work there. What I recommend is to use `with_items` like this:

```
- name: add a new string before the match
  lineinfile: dest=/home/{{ item }}/public_html/wp-config.php 
              regexp=' ... '
  with_items:
   - usera
   - userb
   - userc
```

You can obtain a list of items from a file (`with_lines: cat filename`) or by obtaining them remotely (i.e. from the managed nodes) with, say, a `shell` action and a `register: variable`.